# Meteor Cordova Application Constant Refresh

Tags: angularjs, cordova, meteor

So I've been playing around with Angular-Meteor building a simple little game that's working great as a client. When I go to build it using Cordova for android however my emulator just has a white screen, and on inspection the session is just constantly refreshing while importing dependencies.

I'm aware that the white screen is a general pain point while using Cordova, but has anyone hit this problem and maybe found a good way to debug through it?

EDIT : [Here's a Jing of what I'm talking about](http://screencast.com/t/XrgdXo9I34KV)

Comment: When using a physical device, you can inspect the webview using the desktop Chrome browser. I have not tried this in an emulator.

Comment: I was having a problem with my physical devices connecting, but I was able to connect the inspect with with emulator. I included a jing clip in the original post, here it is again http://screencast.com/t/XrgdXo9I34KV